# How to set transparent background for viewport render of material preview?

Tags: 3d-view, transparency

I want to render material preview with openGL (viewport render), but can't figure out where is alpha setting for the background. There is just *World Opacity* in shading settings, which doesn't affect material preview's hdr image.

In 2.79b it looked like this:

[image]

Comment: is it not the Transparent option in the Render panel > Film?

Comment: Nope, Film's option is for final renders

Comment: @moonboots, haha, yes it is that simple. I just needed to do actual View -> Viewport render to get transparent BG, but somehow expected to see result directly in view area.